# install python collections

Tags: python, qiime

i'm trying to install a program called qiime http://qiime.org/install/install.html and I have finished installing prerequisites and building and installing as per the instructions but I'm stuck because python cant find defaultdict Counter. I googled to install defaultdict but I found nothing. How do you install defaultdict and counter?
This is the error I'm getting. 
Thanks

```
casey@casey-laptop:~/Downloads/Qiime-1.5.0/tests$ cd
casey@casey-laptop:~$ align_seqs.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/align_seqs.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qiime.util import parse_command_line_parameters, get_options_lookup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/qiime/util.py", line 25, in <module>
    from collections import defaultdict, Counter
ImportError: cannot import name Counter

casey@casey-laptop:~/Downloads/Qiime-1.5.0/tests$ python all_tests.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "all_tests.py", line 10, in <module>
    from qiime.util import (parse_command_line_parameters, get_options_lookup,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/qiime/util.py", line 25, in <module>
    from collections import defaultdict, Counter
ImportError: cannot import name Counter
```

Comment: @glglgl Sometimes people can solve their own problems by thinking about version numbers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That *qiime* program seems to use the `Counter` class of the `collections` module. However that was introduced with Python 2.7 and you use Python 2.6.

So updating your Python to 2.7 (or installing 2.7 besides 2.6) is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

[class collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is

> New in version 2.7.